# Unable to export Core ML model in Turicreate

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, coreml, turi-create

I used AWS Sagemaker with Jupyter notebook to train my Turicreate model. It trained successfully but I'm unable to export it to a CoreML model. It shows the below error. I've tried various kernels in the Jupyter notebook with the same result. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

turicreate 5.4
GPU: mxnet-cu100

```
KeyError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3499bdb76e06> in <module>()
  1 # Export for use in Core ML
----> 2 model.export_coreml('pushupsTC.mlmodel')

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/toolkits/object_detector/object_detector.py in export_coreml(self, filename,     include_non_maximum_suppression, iou_threshold, confidence_threshold)
1216         assert (self._model[23].name == 'pool5' and
1217                 self._model[24].name == 'specialcrop5')
-> 1218         del net._children[24]
1219         net._children[23] = op
1220 

KeyError: 24
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Turi Create. You could try using the latest version from master rather than the official release.